# Why is the slowdown of the compiled code evaluation so significant?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, syntax, compile

**Edit**

I have reduced the powers of trigonometric functions entering `formula1`, `formula2` to make the problem clearer. It seems that the powers of `Cos[z],Sin[z]` do not affect the problem.

Consider two groups of formulas:

```
formula1[e_, x_, y_, z_] = 
  e^2 (Sin[x]*Cos[y]*Cos[z] + Sin[x] + 
      Sin[x] Cos[y]^2*(Sin[z] + Cos[z])) + 
   e*(Sin[x]^2*Cos[y]^2*Sin[z]*Cos[z] + Cos[z]*Sin[x]*Cos[y]^2) + 
   Sqrt[e] (Cos[x]*Sin[y]*Cos[z]*Sin[z] + Sin[y] + Cos[x]^2 Sin[z]) + 
   Sin[y]^2*Cos[y]^2;
formula2[e_, x_, y_, z_] = 
  formula1[e, x, y, z] /. {x -> y, y -> x, z -> -z};
formula10[e_, x_, y_] = 
 formula1[e, x, y, z] /. {Sin[z] -> 1, Cos[z] -> 1} /. {z -> 1}
formula20[e_, x_, y_] = 
  formula2[e, x, y, z] /. {Sin[z] -> 1, Cos[z] -> 1} /. {z -> 1};
formula11[e_, x_, y_, sinz_, cosz_] = 
  formula1[e, x, y, z] /. {Sin[z] -> sinz, Cos[z] -> cosz};
formula21[e_, x_, y_, sinz_, cosz_] = 
  formula2[e, x, y, z] /. {Sin[z] -> sinz, Cos[z] -> cosz};
```

`formula10` is simpler than `formula1` as it does not depend on `z`.

Next, consider some data:

```
Dataxy = Join[ArcCos[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10^7, 1}]], 
   RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}, {10^7, 1}], 2];
ezvals = Join[RandomReal[{0.5, 100}, {50, 1}], 
   RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}, {50, 1}], 2];
evals = ezvals[[All, 1]];
zvals = ezvals[[All, 2]];
```

and some test codes evaluating some conditions involving `formula1,formula2` and `formula10,formula20`:

```
compiled1 = 
 Hold@Compile[{{Dataxy, _Real, 1}, {ezvals, _Real, 2}}, 
      Module[{count, xvals, yvals, eval, zval, val1, val2, val3, len},
       count = 0.;
       xvals = Compile`GetElement[Dataxy, 1];
       yvals = Compile`GetElement[Dataxy, 2];
       len = Length[ezvals];
       Do[eval = Compile`GetElement[ezvals, i, 1];
        val1 = formula10[eval, xvals, yvals];
        val2 = formula20[eval, xvals, yvals];
        count += Boole[val1 > 30 && 10 < val2 < 30];
        , {i, 1, len, 1}];
       count
       ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}] /. DownValues@formula10 /. 
   DownValues@formula20 // ReleaseHold

compiled2 = 
 Hold@Compile[{{Dataxy, _Real, 1}, {ezvals, _Real, 2}}, 
      Module[{count, xvals, yvals, eval, zval, val1, val2, val3, len},
       count = 0.;
       xvals = Compile`GetElement[Dataxy, 1];
       yvals = Compile`GetElement[Dataxy, 2];
       len = Length[ezvals];
       Do[eval = Compile`GetElement[ezvals, i, 1];
        zval = Compile`GetElement[ezvals, i, 2];
        val1 = formula1[eval, xvals, yvals, zval];
        val2 = formula2[eval, xvals, yvals, zval];
        count += Boole[val1 > 30 && 10 < val2 < 30];
        , {i, 1, len, 1}];
       count
       ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}] /. DownValues@formula1 /. 
   DownValues@formula2 // ReleaseHold
```

My question is why `compiled2` is much slower than `compiled1`:

```
compiled1[Dataxy, ezvals]; // AbsoluteTiming
compiled2[Dataxy, ezvals]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.91631, Null}

> {2.52246, Null}

After making some cross-checks, it seems to me that the compiled code evaluates `sin(z)`, `cos(z)` only once and then just powers them, so there is no problem with various powers of trigonometric functions entering `formula1`, `formula2`. In addition, evaluating `Sin[z]` and `Cos[z]` even many times should not lead to the observable slowdown:

```
opts = {CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"};
xs = RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}, 50000000];
sin = Compile[{{xs, _Real, 1}}, Do[Sin[x], {x, xs}], Evaluate@{opts}];
cos = Compile[{{xs, _Real, 1}}, Do[Cos[x], {x, xs}], Evaluate@{opts}];
{#, Module[{f = ToExpression[#]}, 
     First@AbsoluteTiming[f[xs];]]} & /@ {"sin", "cos"} // Column
```

> {  {{"sin", 0.0000109}},
>
> {{"cos", 4.4*10^-6}} }

Could you please tell me what is a reason for this slowdown, and whether it is possible to fix it?

Comment: I guess the slowdown is caused entirely by the `Power` function which translates to the `pow` in C. And that one is infamous for being needlessly slow for integer powers. With the substitution `{Sin[z] -> 1, Cos[z] -> 1}` you get terms like `1^5` which are easy to optimize away.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher : Thanks! However, I have later modified `function1`, `function2` by reducing the powers of `Sin[z]`, `Cos[z]` to 1, also reducing the powers of trigonometic functions depending on `x,y` (please see the updated definitions), but the problem remains practically unaffected (0.91 seconds vs 2.51 seconds for `compiled1` and `compiled2`).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher : please ignore my deleted comment. So, the problem is still there (please see my last comment).

Comment: In `Do[Sin[x], {x, xs}]` the compiler sees that there is no return value and just optimizes the loop away. Nothing is done in the function `sin`. When you change `Do` to `Table` will takes substantially longer. So yes, the difference in runtim is due to the trigonometric functions.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher : Thanks! Would it then make sense to evaluate these `Sin[z],Cos[z]` once outside the loop (as they are always the same), and then just call them?

Comment: Of coursem, this does make sense! `Sin` and `Cos` take several times longer than basic arithmetic operations like `+`, `*`, or `-`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher : is it also true for the values `Cos[x], Sin[x], Cos[y], Sin[y]` computed using the data `Dataxy`? Or the compiler may already take care of this by looking at the code?